# Excel: Searching for multiple terms in a cell and return the found value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to scan a column and search for terms inside a cell.
Once any of these terms are found, place the found one in another cell.

The terms are in a named range, I call it "namedrangeOfApps" with over 400 rows.

This is what I have now but instead of returning TRUE I want to return the actual value found.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"namedrangeOfApps"},G2)))>0
```

Example of a cell could be:

"Microsoft.Office.v.21" In this case, if either Microsoft and or Office is found" Place the found entry in another Cell instead of just placing TRUE.

[Source of original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803944/excel-searching-for-multiple-terms-in-a-cell/14804422?noredirect=1#comment86875700_14804422)

Comment: No only one value is returned in one hit.. Each cell has a long string of names of applications. I have placed the names that I am looking for  (i.e ) "Adobe, Microsoft, Google, Office" in a named range and I want to search each row and when I find an occurrence of these terms, place that term in another cell. (instead of TRUE). Example of a cell could be: "Microsoft.Office.v.21" In this case if either Microsoft and or Office is found" Place the found entry in another Cell.

Answer (score 2):

With text in cell **A1** try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Office ",A1)),"Office","") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Adobe ",A1)),"Adobe","") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("google ",A1)),"google","") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Microsoft ",A1)),"Microsoft","")
```

[image]

While it does appear a little "brute force", it is easy to understand and will return more than one keyword if more than one keyword is present.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a small User Defined Function.  Its arguments are the cell being searched and a list of keywords *(in the sample, it is a Named Range called "mikee" in column **C**)*:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function RetrieveKeys(rin As Range, KeyList As Range) As String
    Dim s As String, r As Range

    s = rin(1).Text
    RetrieveKeys = ""
    For Each r In KeyList
        If InStr(1, s, r.Value) > 0 Then RetrieveKeys = RetrieveKeys & r.Value
    Next r
End Function
```

[image]

It can handle a very large list of keywords and if a separator is required between multiple returns, it is easy to change.

Comment: The list of keywords is over 400 which is why I have them in a named range. Although this solution works, I would have to create 400 if(isnumber) statements. Instead of =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Adobe ","Microsoft ","google ","Office "},G2)))>0   I have =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({NamedRangeOfApps},G2)))>0 .. Perhaps I was not clear.

Comment: @Stryker  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @garys-student Still processing. Super slow on 300,000 row with a named range containing 400 rows. so far 30% done..

Comment: Try on small sample first

Comment: A little slow but it does the job. Will accept and post a question perhaps there is a better way to approach my problem: I have a list of all apps (30,000) installed on all laptops (5000), col A list the machine ID, Col B list the apps. Hence Col A has duplicates. Since each machine has many apps. And need to find out which apps are win 10 compatible? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({NamedRange1},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({NamedRange1},A10)),0)),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"microsoft", "google", "apple"},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"microsoft", "google", "apple"},A10)),0)),"")
```

This works great

reference...

[Searching for multiple text strings in a MS Excel cell and return the same string when found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768906/searching-for-multiple-text-strings-in-a-ms-excel-cell-and-return-the-same-strin/47770154#47770154)